# PHP Executes File Twice When Link Is Clicked

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, fopen, execute

I'm having a weird issue on my site. Whenever a link is clicked the file is being executed twice. The only reason that I noticed this was because when I would submit a search request for keywords, I log the search in our MySQL database. The database was always saving two records (there was a time stamp and the records were added sometimes in the same second, but usually only a second apart). I knew that I was the only one on the site and that the query wasn't getting called in a loop. So I did a fopen($file, 'a') to see how many lines of code would be added and there were most of the time two lines of code added. The only way that I could get one record to add was if I ran the same search 2-3 times in a row.

So the only thing I can think of is that we have goodle ads on our site. the only thing I can imagine that's happening is that when I click the link, the javascript that's tied to the ad also follows the same link.

Any other brilliant ideas?

Comment: Please show us the code for the page with the link, and then for the php.

Comment: Can you show us the code on the button?

Comment: Maybe something being `include`d twice?

Comment: Try commenting out the Adsense code and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer I just posted. Big Brother.... ha! @cillosis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should I be scared?

I commented out the code for google ads as soon as I wrote this post (and saw @cillosis suggested).

I don't have the problem anymore. It totally was Google though. This was in my apache access log every time I'd run a search.

```
66.249.73.87 - - [16/May/2012:12:38:45 -0500] "GET /search.php?page_num=1&keywords=stylist&city=&state=AL&cat= HTTP/1.1" 200 14185 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
```

I'm scared.....

Answer (score 5):

I've seen such symptoms when there was an asset (image, js, css) without an actual link, like:

```
<img src="" />
```

in this case the browser tried to fetch the same url, but with different `Accept` header. Log it, that shall help to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

When processing a form, check to see that they actually clicked the submit button like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'submit') {
   // Process form
} else {
   // Just display it
}
```

This will prevent you from processing it twice. You should also redirect after a form post using a 303 redirect.